# Why does Calamity Ganon have Daruk's Protection?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In the cut scenes for Mipha, Daruk, and Revali, it is made clear that each of their respective powers (healing, protection, upwards draft) is an ability unique to them (if not genetic as Daruk's offspring also have his ability of protection). When clearing the Divine Beasts their spirits transfer these gifts to you (i.e. they are willfully given).

So how come, when facing Calamity Ganon, he has the ability of Daruk's Protection? Yes he has other elemental abilities, but he displays none of the other Champions' powers.

Comment: Welcome on Arqade! I took the liberty to reformat your question to further prevent spoilers, feel free to revert. (I struggled a bit, the spoilers syntax does weird things)

Comment: A question must make sense without spoiler tags.  As there's no question here without what was in the spoilers, I have removed them.  Here at Arqade, we don't dance around questions; just ask them.

Comment: Okay, I guess you're right. Sorry!

Answer (score 5):

Seeing that he doesnt have the other 3, it would seem that this is not Daruks protection.

It might be a similar ability,  but its probably not the same thing.

Comment: It has the same coloration and stylistic effects as Daruk's protection as well as in game effect (perfect guard). I get it if they were just trying to make Ganon harder (because lets face it, he was ridiculously easy in this game), but then why use the same effects which the game so very firmly ties to Daruk's protection?

Comment: @SumNeuron For UX reasons -- the player would immediately recognise the effect and understand what it does. If you made an effect that was functionally identical but visually completely different, it would confuse them. One possible alternative is to give ganon's the same visual effect but just recolor it, but I guess orange is pretty much his themed color in that fight, so

Comment: So on a gameplay perspective, it is the same thing. In a lore perspective, it isn't. NOBODY PAGE MATPAT ON THIS. You know he will make a Game Theory about this.

Answer (score 5):

Calamity Ganon is inheriting certain Abilities from the Blight Bosses

> inside the Divine Beasts which all seem to share Abilities of the Champion counterparts in a similar fashion.

For example the shield he gets during his second phase seems near identical (with the exception of immunity to bombs which is changed to his own laser amongst ) with the ability that

> Fireblight Ganon uses in his second Phase of the fight. which blocks off nearly any damage inflicked to him with only very little weaknesses to pass the shield.

Comment: I don't think that is necessarily true... For example for the water based one that Ganon mini-boss stays strictly above water and throws water based projections - things we have not seen any Zora do. Mipha was that beasts champion and the blight boss never healed itself... If anything the only connection was that the beast was weak to electricity. As for Fireblight Ganon's shield that was a flame barrier produced as he made the mini meteor (hence the wind guest) which we see none of in the final fight against Ganon (in relation to his shield, although there still is the meteor)

Comment: The Water based Boss necessarily had the least common aspects in comparison with Mipha, with  the exception of using a spear like she did. But The ice abilities do have a lore-based explanation with the freezing of Zoras Domain. The shield that Ganon uses uses the same orb at the beginning as Daruks Boss does, only to be active immediately, and without the need of a dodongo inhale buffer.

Comment: Waterblight's ice cube ability is identical to Vah Ruta's. To me it seems like the Blights mimick the Champion's preferred weapon type, but the Divine Beast's ability.

Answer (score 1):

Calamity Ganon has a few of the same abilities as the Fireblight Ganon and WaterBlight Ganon inside the Divine Beasts. To make this a fact is because Calamity Ganon uses the fire shield and uses a fire blade the same as FireBight Ganon, and he throws a huge spear like WaterBlight Ganon.